# regarding groupby(level=0) and unstack() in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

There is a dataframe looks like as follows

```
activities_by_gender
      sport           gender    count
0   treadmill walking   male    2
1   step counter        male    2
2   swimming           unknown  8
3   fitness walking    male     228
4   circuit training   female   22
```

The following code will generate a dataframe looks like as follows. I am not very clear how to analyze the working meahchism of the chain operation in this code, especially, how do the `groupby(level=0)` and `unstack()`  work in the following command.

```
temp=activities_by_gender.groupby(['sport', 'gender']).agg(np.mean).groupby(level=0).apply(
    lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()).unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output of `activities_by_gender.groupby(['sport', 'gender']).agg(np.mean)` code is `DataFrame` with MultiIndex by `sport, gender` levels.

So if add:

```
.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum())
```

it means grouping by first level, here `sport` and applied custom lambda function, last is used `unstack` for pivoting - it means converting last level, here `gender` to columns.

Data was changed for better see, how it working:

```
print (activities_by_gender)
               sport   gender  count
0  treadmill walking     male      2
1  treadmill walking     male      5
2  treadmill walking  unknown      8
3    fitness walking     male     10
4    fitness walking   female     22
```

---

```
print (activities_by_gender.groupby(['sport', 'gender']).agg(np.mean))
                           count
sport             gender        
fitness walking   female    22.0
                  male      10.0
treadmill walking male       3.5 <- aggregate mean (duplicates treadmill walking, male)
                  unknown    8.0

 #divided summed sports and multiple 100
print (activities_by_gender.groupby(['sport', 'gender']).agg(np.mean)
                            .groupby(level=0).apply( lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()))
                               count
sport             gender            
fitness walking   female   68.750000
                  male     31.250000
treadmill walking male     30.434783
                  unknown  69.565217
                  
#gender level to columns names - pivoting
temp=(activities_by_gender.groupby(['sport', 'gender']).agg(np.mean)
                          .groupby(level=0).apply( lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum())
                          .unstack())
print (temp)
                   count                      
gender            female       male    unknown
sport                                         
fitness walking    68.75  31.250000        NaN
treadmill walking    NaN  30.434783  69.565217
```

Idea for improve solution - first is used [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and then is divide values summed per `axis=1` with multiple `100`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='sport', columns='gender', values='count', aggfunc='mean')
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100)
print (df)
gender             female       male    unknown
sport                                          
fitness walking     68.75  31.250000        NaN
treadmill walking     NaN  30.434783  69.565217
```

Comment: really appreciate your detailed answer.